# mySQL TIME with fractional seconds clipping after decimal

Tags: mysql, time

I am trying to add stopwatch timing to a database in mySQL.  The docs for 5.6 state fractional seconds is now allowed.

ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html

But when I actually try and do it, the database clips the decimal part. I also noted that even though I choose the column type as `TIME(3)`, its put a `(HH:MM:SS)` next it.  Missing completely the fractional part.

A user inputs the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds (hh:mm:ss.ms) and I remove the `:`, as per instructions.  No date is involved in this.  but it still clips off the end.

How would I prevent this clipping, is it how the column is set up ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's for 5.6.4+. if you're on 5.6.3 and older, then that doesn't apply.

Comment: That would be why, i am on 5.6.21.  Ill get it updated.  Thank you,i missed that.